# Ficheros, sacar los productos por orden alfabetico y los mas vendidos en mayusculas

Tags: java, archivo

Buenas tengo el siguiente problema: 
Dado el siguiente fichero: ventas.txt

```
platanos 5
fresas 8
fresas 3
arandanos 10
peras 2
platanos 1
```

Sacar los productos en orden alfabetico, acumulados y los mas vendidos en mayusculas.
Ejemplo de ejecucion:

```
arandanos 10
FRESAS 11
peras 2
platanos 6
```

Yo he intentado esto pero no me sale ni de lejos.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    File f = new File("/home/unknow/Documentos/ventas.txt");

    try
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(f);

        int recolector;
        int mayor = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        String palabra;
        String palabraMayor;
        while(sc.hasNext())
        {
            recolector = sc.nextInt();
            palabra = sc.nextLine();
            if(recolector > mayor)
            {
                mayor = recolector;
                palabraMayor = palabra.toUpperCase();
            }

        }
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Fichero no encontrado.");
    }


}
```

No se como hacer para que me seleccione solo los numeros de cada linea aparte de los nombres.

Comment: Hola, ¿Es un ejercicio de estudios? De ser así es probable que quieran que trabajes con las interfaces `Comparator`y `Comparable`.

Comment: Este ejemplo va a marcar error ya que estas obteniendo un valor entero recolector = sc.nextInt(); y se supone que es un valor alfanumerico en cada linea, el nombre y la cantidad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo te voy a ayudar con una parte de tu problema, que no es otra de **separar** lo que recibes por consola en un `String` y en un entero `'int'`, y así poder trabajar con esas variables. También te ayudo a la hora de ordenar **alfabéticamente** 'con una *actualización que he hecho'* los resultados.

> Para ello vamos a trabajar con el método `split()` el cual divide una cadena de las coincidencias de una expresión regular pasada como parámetro 'un espacio en blanco en este caso'.

**1)** Primeramente creo un array de tipo `Object[]` para poder almacenar lo que nos llega por consola..

- Antes de entrar en el while().. `Object[] renglon;`
- Y dentro del while.. `renglon = sc.nextLine().split(" ");`

---

**2)** Ahora separamos en **2 variables** y almacenamos por un lado la fruta de tipo `String`, y por otro lado el número de piezas en un entero `int`.

```
String fruta = (String) renglon[0];
int numero = Integer.parseInt((String)renglon[1]);
```

---

**3)** Y ahora imprimimos por consola lo que nos devuelve cada una de estas variables..

```
System.out.println("Fruta: "+ fruta + " y he vendido "+numero+" piezas");
```

**Resultado:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

#### El ejemplo al completo:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        File f = new File("C:\\Development\\ficheros\\ventas.txt");

        try {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(f);
            Object[] renglon;
            while (sc.hasNext()) {
                renglon = sc.nextLine().split(" ");
                String fruta = (String) renglon[0];
                int numero = Integer.parseInt((String) renglon[1]);

                System.out.println("Fruta: " + fruta + " y he vendido " + numero + " piezas");

            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Fichero no encontrado.");
        }
    }
```

---

---

### Edito o Actualización..

Para hacer una ordenación y poder comparar valores y demás, yo crearía una clase POJO a parte..

```
class MiFruta {
    String fruta;
    int pieza;

    public MiFruta(String fruta, int pieza){
        this.fruta = fruta;
        this.pieza = pieza;
    }

    public String getFruta() {
        return fruta;
    }

    public void setFruta(String fruta) {
        this.fruta = fruta;
    }

    public int getPieza() {
        return pieza;
    }

    public void setPieza(int pieza) {
        this.pieza = pieza;
    }

}
```

---

En la clase donde extraemos del fichero crearía una lista para ir guardando las frutas con las respectivas piezas.

```
List<MiFruta> lasFrutas = new ArrayList<>();
```

Dentro del while inicializamos cada uno de los objetos de la clase MiFruta

```
MiFruta frutasVarias = new MiFruta(fruta, numero);
```

Y los añadimos a nuestra lista

```
lasFrutas.add(frutasVarias);
```

Y ya fuera del while podríamos hacer las comparaciones e imprimirlos en orden alfabético por ejemplo..

```
System.out.println("----------Despues de ordenar nuestras frutas---------");
Collections.sort(lasFrutas, Comparator.comparing(MiFruta::getFruta));
for (MiFruta mf : lasFrutas){
    System.out.print("MiFruta "+ mf.getFruta());
    System.out.println("..Piezas "+ mf.getPieza());
}
```

**Y nos arrojaría como resultado..**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Igual que he hecho el cast `(String)`, lo podía haber hecho de esta otra manera `renglon[0].toString()`

Comment: A la hora de hacer la comparación, lo he hecho así para no tener que implementar la interfaz `Comparator` en la clase MiFruta.